# Parent-child relationship in User model (self join)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails, I have this User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:adult, :child, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  # belongs_to :spouse, :foreign_key => :spouse_id, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :spouse 

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :adult
  end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  def marry(user)
    self.spouse = user
    user.spouse = self
  end
end
```

I added spouses through this migration:

```
class AddFieldsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # for marriages
    add_column :users, :spouse_id, :integer, index: true
  end
end
```

and that works decently (though my inverse of function never worked `# belongs_to :spouse, :foreign_key => :spouse_id, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :spouse`
). I am now trying to do another self join with a "child-parent" relationship. A parent can have many children and a child can have (many / two) parents. This is the migration I came up with:

```
class CreateParentalRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :parental_relationships do |t|
      t.references :parent, index: true
      t.references :child
    end
  end
end
```

and I added this to the model:

```
  has_many :children, :through => :parental_relationships, class_name: "User"
  has_many :parents, :through => :parental_relationships, class_name: "User"
```

but the relationship did not work with the following error:

```
[7] pry(main)> u = User.find(3)
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
=> #<User id: 3, email: ...>

[8] pry(main)> u.children
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :parental_relationships in model Us
er

[9] pry(main)> u.parent
NoMethodError: undefined method `parent' for #<User:0x5e52eb0>
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in
 `method_missing'

[10] pry(main)> u.parents
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :parental_relationships in model Us
er
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:690:in `che
ck_validity!'

[11] pry(main)> u2.children
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :parental_relationships in model Us
er
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:690:in `che
ck_validity!'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by **relationship did not work**?

Comment: I guess you have to add `has_many :parental_relationships` also to the `User` model.

Comment: You were right, and I had a bunch of other things to change as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting up the parent child relationship takes some finagling.

```
class ParentalRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :child, class_name: 'User'
end
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parent_relationships,
          foreign_key: 'child_id',
          class_name: 'ParentalRelationship'

  has_many :child_relationships,
          foreign_key: 'parent_id',
          class_name: 'ParentalRelationship'

  has_many :parents,
          through: :parent_relationships,
          class_name: 'User'

  has_many :children,
          through: :child_relationships,
          class_name: 'User'

  has_and_belongs_to_many :marriages
  belongs_to :current_marriage, class_name: 'Marriage'

  def marry(spouse)
    marriage = Marriage.create(users: [self, spouse])
    marriage.users.each { |u| u.update(current_marriage: marriage ) }
    marriage
  end

  def spouse
    return nil unless current_marriage
    current_marriage
      .users.where.not('marriages_users.user_id' => id).first
  end

  def birth(child)
    child.parents << self
    child.parents << spouse if spouse
  end
end
```

Note that we need to setup the relation to `ParentalRelationship` twice since we need to tell rails which foreign key it should look at for each type of relation (user is parent or child).

---

Since in these modern times people can actually have be married several times we need a Marriage model and a join table for users_marriages.

```
class Marriage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  validates :users, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 2 }
end
```

---

```
rails g migration CreateUsersMarriagesJoinTable users marriages
```

Example app with specs: https://github.com/maxcal/sandbox/tree/31614819

Comment: I omitted polygamous marriage support for brevity :)

Comment: I would also use a Role class and set the relation as `User` `has_many :roles`. Role `belongs_to: user`. Since limiting the user to one role is usually not a good design. Check out [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution. Not sure if it is the best:

my new User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:adult, :child, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  belongs_to :spouse, :foreign_key => :spouse_id, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :spouse
  has_many :parental_relationships
  has_many :children, :through => :parental_relationships, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :parents, :through => :parental_relationships, class_name: 'User'

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :adult
  end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  def marry(user)
    self.spouse = user
    user.spouse = self
  end

  def birth(user)
    self.children << user
    user.parents << self
    if self.spouse
      self.spouse.children << user
      user.parents << self.spouse
    end

  end

end
```

I had to edit a few migrations and models.

ParentalRelationships migration

```
class CreateParentalRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :parental_relationships do |t|

      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :child 
      t.references :parent

    end
  end
end
```

ParentalRelationship model:

```
class ParentalRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  # , :class_name => "User"
  # belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :child, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "User"
end
```

So, to add relationships:

```
u = User.find(50)
u.birth(User.find(60))
```